# Custom Ribbon button in CRM new release Orion?

Tags: crm, workbench, dynamics-crm-2013

Does any body have idea about whether Custom Ribbon button is supported or not in CRM new release Orion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Orion official name is Dynamics CRM 2013. Currently the product (for who has access) is under NDA.

But from the public information available the "new" ribbon is customizable, in fact Scott Durow released a new version of his tool Ribbon Workbench for CRM 2013.

You can download from here:

http://www.develop1.net/public/page/Ribbon-Workbench-for-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx